# Smart playlist changes to normal playlist in banshee while syncing to ipod nano.

Tags: sync, banshee, ipod

When I sync my ipod from banshee, the smart playlist becomes normal playlist in my ipod. Also I can only sync one playlist.

Answer (score 0):

Banshee is limited in its ability to work with Ipods.

Try GTKPod, it is a dedicated Ipod manager and should meet you needs

```
sudo apt-get install gtkpod
```